# Как установить background в ImageView программно?

Tags: java, android

У меня такой простой вопрос я хочу сделать световой индикатор из моего ImageView как мне установить в него цвет? Наверное таких вопросов в нете очень мало так как я ниче не нашел...
Вот я устанавливаю так из XML файла

```
android:background="#fa2255"
```

Но как из кода такое сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если просто цвет в бэк, то так:
`img.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("ваш цвет"));`